# renaming multipe columns with simmilar names in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm renaming columns with similar names in my dataframe.

This code works fine however i want to make it stop after renaming every three columns then rest and continue renaming the next three columns.

```
cols = []
count = 1
for column in df.columns:
    if column == 'Stabilized Roll':
        cols.append(f'Stabilized Roll_scenario{count}')
        count+=1
        continue
    cols.append(column)
df.columns = cols
```

my input is

```
|Stabilized Roll|   Stabilized Roll|    Stabilized Roll|    Stabilized Roll |Stabilized Roll|   Stabilized Roll|
0.142858    -0.04979    -0.05819    -0.06655    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142858    -0.04979    -0.05819    -0.06655    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018307
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018307
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018307
0.142863    -0.05041    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018307
```

The desired output is

```
|subject 1 Stabilized Roll_scenario1|   subject 1 Stabilized Roll_scenario2|    subject 1 Stabilized Roll_scenario3|    subject 2 Stabilized Roll_scenario1|    |subject 2 Stabilized Roll_scenario2|   subject 2 Stabilized Roll_scenario3 |
0.142858    -0.04979    -0.05819    -0.06655    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142858    -0.04979    -0.05819    -0.06655    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018312
0.142863    -0.05012    -0.05927    -0.06576    -0.04666    0.018307
```

Comment: kindly post sample data, with expected output

Comment: Can you post `print (df.columns)` with expected output after renaming each three columns like you need?

Comment: @jezrael i have added the input and the output. Sorry it's quite messy i couldnt add it in tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division by `3` with add 1 with modulo by `3` for `scenario`:

```
count = 0
```

and then:

```
cols.append(f'subject {count // 3 + 1} Stabilized Roll_scenario{count % 3 + 1}')
```